# Firestore and Angular 7 problem with the subscribe method

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore in angular 7 to receive data. When I register with subscribe to the observable, the complete method is never executed.
An idea?
My code is the following:

```
  getMesuresJours(nombreJours: number): Observable<Mesure[]> {
    const _date = moment().startOf('day').subtract(nombreJours, 'days');
    return this.afs.collection(this.path, ref =>
                      ref.where('dateMesure', '>=', _date.toDate())
                         .orderBy('dateMesure', 'desc'))
                .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
                  return changes.map(donnees => {
                    const mesure = donnees.payload.doc.data() as Mesure;
                    const _dateMesure: any = mesure.dateMesure;
                    // convertion de la date du serveur (Timestamp)
                    // en date Javascript pour puovoir l'afficher
                    // au niveau des graphes
                    mesure.dateMesure = (_dateMesure as firestore.Timestamp).toDate();
                    return mesure;
                  });
                }));
```

Use of the service:

```
getMesures() {
    this.mesureService.getMesuresJours(this.nombrePeriode).subscribe({
        next: donnees => {
          this.mesures = donnees;
          console.log(this.mesures);
          if (this.mesures.length !== 0) {
            this.data = this.chartService.getFormatData(this.mesures, this.nombrePeriode, this.option);
           }
        },
        error: err => { console.log('Erreur lors de la recupération des données :', err); },
        complete: () => { console.log('Recupération complete'); }
      }
    );
  }
```

complete: ()=> ... is never executed.

In addition, when I change the value of the variable numberPeriod
in the ***next*** block of the ***getMesure()*** method , the observable sends me the previous data first before the news.
How to solve this problem and do

```
this.mesures = donnees;
   console.log(this.mesures);
    if (this.mesures.length !== 0) {
                    this.data = this.chartService.getFormatData(this.mesures, this.nombrePeriode, this.option);
    }
```

only when the new data arrives?

Comment: Complete won't be called, unless you stop the connection to firebase, or change the user. Firebase is a stream of data with real-time updates

Comment: when you unsubscribe the observable then it will be executed. I think you need `finalize` operator. try this https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize

Comment: Thank you.
I change my post before seeing your answers.
But how to wait for the arrival of new data before assigning them to my variable measures[] ?